# Prevent Leading Whitespace with RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input, validation

I'm trying to restrict review posting text with (at the present) the following RegEx:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 _\.\'\"\(\)\!\?\&\@]){1,}$
```

However,  the text itself needs to contain whitespace in the form of ' ', but I don't want to allow the first sentence to have whitespace, i.e. the post cannot have leading whitespace.  For an example, (I'm going to use '_' to represent ' ' in the following example) the form would allow:

`This is a sentence.`

But it would NOT allow:

> (Using '_' to represent ' ')
>
> `_This is a sentence`
>
> `__This is a sentence`
>
> etc.

I tried to work with negations, but I just don't understand RegEx well enough to grasp how to do this.  This whole field is just not sitting well with me, so hopefully someone can help.  Thanks in advance!

NOTE:
I need this in RegEx because I have a live-feed validator telling the user that his/her input is valid/invalid.  Another option that will allow me this real-time awareness will be sufficient for my purposes, if you happen to think of something better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$
```

Comment: +1 ah, forgot about lookahead... again ;) (no need to escape the characters in the character group).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow these characters with the restriction that the first one should not be a whitespace, you have to repeat the character group:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@][a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@\s]+$/
```

Or you make two tests:

```
if(!/^\s/.test(str) && /^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]+$/.test(str)) {
    // valid
}
```

Comment: This only prevents 1 instance of ' ', how do I expand that to prevent a theoretical infinite amount?

Comment: @Matt: Are you talking about the first or second expression? If the first character is not a white space, everything is fine, isn't it?

Comment: No, I needed the absence of any amount of whitespace prior to text.  That's why I showed the example above with 2 whitespaces also not working.

Comment: @Matt: I think you are over-complicating the problem. No matter how many whitespace there are at the beginning, the first character will always be one. Therefore it is sufficient to test the first character only. If it is not a white space, it is a letter, so there are no leading white spaces. But I'm actually not sure how you are applying the expression, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ^\S at the beginning of your regex, where the '^' is the beginning of the string, and '\S' is the negation of the whitespace character class.